# Snap mouse position to element's boundary

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am creating a floor plan editor in RaphaelJs. The rooms are dynamically created by clicking and then dragging a mouse. I have two questions:

1: Is there any way that I can snap the mouse position (onclick) to the boundary of an element, provided that the click has happened within a distance of, lets say, 5 pixels.

2: Is there a way that I can determine if mouse is clicked (or hovers) upon the boundary of an element that is `fill`ed. The `getElementByPoint` function will tell me the same only if the element is not `fill`.

EDIT: I have a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/sDP7A/2/ .
When I am creating a new element at the boundary of another element. I want the boundaries of both the elements to exactly match. However if you notice depending upon where you click (across the width of the older element), there is a slight mismatch between the old element and the new element.

So if my mouse can snap to the old element when I am creating a new element, I can assure that the boundaries match.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle, provide here some code ?

Comment: Hmm can't seem to get it to work..

Comment: 1st of all, your `e.pageX`, `e.pageY` point to incorrect coordinates, you have to make it relative to canvas, not to page.

Comment: i have an idea - to attach events not to document, but to elements themself. it will allow you always select correct element

Comment: If I have a function getNearestPointOfElement from (e.pageX,e.pageY) then I can manually snap it - but is there such a function??)

Comment: eicto: did you click on " Create rectangle" radio before you tried to create the element?

Comment: what i mean - when you create rectangle, create not just rectangle, but object with event handlers, methods, etc, than you can easy get all properties of the clicked element, also attach handler to canvas, to get clicks to not elements

Comment: fill rectangles with zero opacity fill to snap to them inside of

Comment: @eicto: Yes , I will try that. The snap part should be easily implemented. Thanks suggestion

Comment: also object model will help you to "remember" all attached elements when you move "parent"

Comment: Nah... once I put my mind to the attaching events to elements, I still cant get around snapping to the boundary :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21100/discussion-between-eicto-and-user1517108)